# Excel Data Model: Prevent whole-category averaging

Tags: excel, pivot

I am new to data models.

In the following picture, I would expect the "Average of Reading" and "Average of Science" to show the individual value for each ID when drilled all the way down. Instead I am getting the average of all "Reading" and all "Science."

The ID is the value that all the relationships are build on in the data model.

"Average of Math" is displaying exactly as I would expect it to.

How can I fix this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMPgJ.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this through trial and error.

You need a "Master" sheet, that has all demographic/whatever identifiers.

You use the "Master" as the "Related Lookup" table, and the non-Master as the primary table in all the relationships.